# RDNS_NONE from spamassassin result, when it should be positive

Tags: linux, email, spamassassin, ptr-record

When trying to do a spam test on `mail-tester.com`, SpamAssassin is giving me `RDNS_NONE` result.

Can't quite figure out why!

The result I get:

> -1.274    RDNS_NONE   Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
>   This may be a false-positive, please check the reverse DNS test below to confirm or not this issue

But. my records as shown as valid as such;

```
HELO: example.me
rDNS: example.me
```

So this should be fine. Previously I tested it with these values and I get no *RDNS none* flag up, but the rDNS was listed as not being correct

```
HELO: example.me
rDNS: server1.example.me
```

There must be a fault somewhere in my PTR record in my MTA. Can anyone suggest something please or a way to troubleshoot this?

Additional note: I have multiple domains and PTR records on the same server.

Comment: should really add also. I have multiple domains and PTR records on the same server..

Comment: Where are the logs from Spamassasin and your MTA? The headers of the suspicous mail? Maybe the RDNS-warning is for the sending host, not your local mta?

Comment: I have the same issue. You did not find a solution?

Comment: same problem here, rDNS properly setup for same helo domain and still no good